# api is returning an array with numbered and named keys

Tags: javascript, ghost-blog

So I am putting together a NextJS + Ghost CMS decoupled blog and am playing around with the Ghost JS API (specifically the Content API Client Library).

When I run my query using the following...

```
api.posts
    .browse({ 
      limit: 5,
      page: 1,
      include: 'authors',
      fields: 'excerpt,custom_excerpt,title,id,slug,'
    })  
    .then((posts) => {
      console.log(posts);
        return posts;
      })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

... I find that it returning an array. The array had the typical `0` `1` `2` ... keys. I was surprised to find that it ALSO had a named last item: `meta`.

See image from chrome JS console.

[image: is this even possible]

What is going on here. Did I miss a lesson in JS101 about string-named keys on arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description):

> Arrays are **list-like objects** whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations.

In other words, they are a special type of objects. So, like to other `objects`, you can add `named properties` to it. However the `methods` available on his `prototype` only traverses the `numeric-properties`. Check next example:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.meta = {foo: "bar"};
console.log("standard arr display: ", arr);
console.log("arr.meta: ", arr.meta);
console.log("Own Property Names: ", Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Now, I believe that the implementation of the **chrome JS console** is based on an `object` prototype method, maybe [Object.getOwnPropertNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/getOwnPropertyNames), to display all his properties (including the `non-enumerable` **length**) and values. You can give a read to [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to see how to define `non-enumerable` property using the `descriptor` argument.